# $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}$ is a power series with convergence radius $R \in (0,\infty]$ with some conditions,prove that $a_n =0 \forall n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Define $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}$ is a power series with convergence radius $R \in (0,\infty]$. Suppose $\exists$ a sequence $(x_j)_{j\geq1} \in (-R,R)/{0}$ that converges to $0$ and $f(x_j) = 0 \forall j \geq 1$. Show that $a_n=0 \forall n \geq 0$

**My attempt:**

The exercise gives a hint: prove that $a_0 =0$ and after that $a_1=0$ and so forth.

So  $f(x_j) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx_j^{n}=0$ for any $j$, so we have $f(x_j) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx_j^{n}=0$ for any given $j$, so it gives us $ja_0 = $$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} {x_j}^n$ , Since $a_0$ is finite, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} {x_j}^n$ also gotta be finite in order to the original power series yield 0, and as $j \to \infty$ we conclude that $a_0=0$

Now i'm stuck about how to proceed on the other coefficients. Could someone give me a hint, link a question, give material of highlight something?

I'm also a bit confused with so many indexes, I'm not sure if this argument is valid for proving that $a_0=0$, it just seems right.

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask for clarifications. It seems to be easy, but i'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you know continuity of $f$. Since $f(x_j)=0$ for all $j$ we get $a_0=0$ in the limit and this gives $f(0)=0$.

Next consider $g(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-1}$. This is a new power series and I will let you check that it also has radius of convergence $R$. By the result alredy proved with $g$ in place of $f$ we get $g(0)=0$ and this gives $a_1=0$. Now consier $g(x)= \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-2}$, and so on.